# How to enable windows accelerator key highlighting per registry script

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, windows-registry, accelerator

Is it possible to enable windows accelerator key highlighting with a registry script?
And if, how?

Answer (score 0):

It's key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Accessibility\Keyboard Preference`. If it contains string value `On` = `1`, highlighting is enabled.

Comment: Thank you. This seems to be the right key, as it toggles the checkbox in Keyboard Accesibility Window and the display of accelerator keys in SOME programs. But when enabling this via script (even after few reboots) windows dialog boxes like the UAC dialog still don't display the underline and have to be set manually again for me. Is there sth. I might have missed?  using win2012r2

Comment: @MrHas3 - If you enable the checkbox in Keyboard Accesibility Window via the UI, do you get underlined accelerators also in the UAC? In other words, is there a difference when you enable the checkbox vs. when you enable the registry value? This could lead to the answer. What is your Windows version?